# Enhance CSPRNG output

Tags: random-number-generator

If I XOR the output from 2 CSPRNG will the result be better (more random) than the output from either one?
Assume one of the PRNG is biased.

Comment: How are they keyed?  With two independent keys?  Also, if one is a CSPRNG, then it cannot be biased (to be cryptographically secure *means* that it can't be biased).

Answer (score 1):

If you XOR two **independent** streams of two random number generators together then the result is as strong as the strongest of the two.

Comment: More generally, if you XOR the streams of two [**independent**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)) random number generators together then the result is as strong as the strongest of the two. $\;$

Comment: How to determine if two PRNG are independent? I am thinking about using the default apple PRNG secCopyRandomBytes and the AutoSeeded RNG from the Botan library? How do I know that both of them don't do similar things inside?

Comment: "Unrelated" is *NOT* the criterion.  The criterion is that the *keys* be independently chosen, not that the *algorithms* be "unrelated" or "independent" (whatever that would mean).  You can even use the same CSPRNG algorithm, as long as you have two independent keys.

Comment: @D.W. What I meant was that the streams are unrelated, not the algorithms. Updated my answer.

Comment: @user1028028, it doesn't matter if the PRNGs are independent.  What matters is that their seeds (their keys) are independently chosen.  That's how you can tell: check how you've generated them.

Comment: If one is totally unbiased and the other is biased, doesn’t the bias “cut through” into the output stream of XOR, though?